# Projection in D3 v5 not working with coordinates data

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a map of meteorite landings across the world using D3 v5. I have the map displaying. The coordinates (lat, long) from the meteorite json file are loading. I am trying to use them in `.attr` for "cx" and "cy". When I `console.log` the coordinates in `.attr`, they show up, but when I try to pass them through my projection so they will display properly on the map, I am getting the following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'coordinates' of null.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this working? Appreciate any help you can offer.

Here a link to a Codepen: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/QryZPR?editors=0110

And my code:

```
const w = 960;
const h = 600;

const svg = d3.select(".map")
.append("svg")
.attr("height", h)
.attr("width", w);

let projection = d3.geoMercator()
.translate([w/2, h/2])
.scale(140);

const path = d3.geoPath()
.projection(projection);

let tooltip = d3.select("body")
.append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip");

const files = ["https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/meteorite-strike-data.json"];

Promise.all(files.map((url) => d3.json(url))).then(function(data) {

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "country")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(data[0], data[0].objects.countries).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);

  svg.selectAll(".meteor")
  .data(data[1].features)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "meteor")
  .attr("cx", (d) => {
    console.log(d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
    let coords = projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]]);
    return coords[0];
  })
  .attr("cy", (d) => {
    let coords = projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]]);
    return coords[1];
  })
  .attr("r", 6);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is missing coordinates for certain locations, eg:

```
 {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": null,
    "properties": {
      "mass": "2250",
      "name": "Bulls Run",
      "reclong": null,
      "geolocation_address": null,
      "geolocation_zip": null,
      "year": "1964-01-01T00:00:00.000",
      "geolocation_state": null,
      "fall": "Fell",
      "id": "5163",
      "recclass": "Iron?",
      "reclat": null,
      "geolocation_city": null,
      "nametype": "Valid"
    }
  },
```

This generates the error you see, stopping the appending of circles.

You could try to filter them out with something like:

```
svg.selectAll(".meteor")
 .data(data[1].features.filter(function(d) {
  return d.geometry;    // return only features with a geometry
}) )
```

Giving us:

[image]

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqXQYy?editors=0110

---

Also, I'll quickly note that this:

```
projection([d.geometry.coordinates[0], d.geometry.coordinates[1]]);
```

Can be simplified to this:

```
projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
```

Comment: Thanks sir. You're a lifesaver.