# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of undefined

Tags: javascript, geojson, topojson

This is how I am accessing my data:

```
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/meteorite-strike-data.json", 
  function(data){        
    console.log(data);
    states=topojson.feature(data,data.objects.countries).features;
  }
);
```

But it gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'countries' of undefined`

Here is an example of my data:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          6.08333,
          50.775
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "mass": "21",
        "name": "Aachen",
        "reclong": "6.083330",
        "geolocation_address": null,
        "geolocation_zip": null,
        "year": "1880-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        "geolocation_state": null,
        "fall": "Fell",
        "id": "1",
        "recclass": "L5",
        "reclat": "50.775000",
        "geolocation_city": null,
        "nametype": "Valid"
      }
    },
```

Comment: What does the JSON response look like?

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong. You're trying to get `.countries` from `undefined`, which means `data.objects` is `undefined`.

Comment: what is `topojson.feature`?

Answer (score 1):

You are using topojson.js on a geojson file. A topojson contains a property called objects, which contains the features in the file. A topojson always begins with (or at least has the type "topology"):

```
{"type":"Topology",...
```

You have geojson, geojson often contains feature collections (that or an individual feature with type "feature" or geometries of type "polygon","point" etc):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [ ... ]
}
```

Since geojson feature collections (or individual features) don't have a objects property, you get the error you see as objects is undefined.

When using topojson, `topojson.feature()` returns a geojson feature collection, but since you already have geojson feature collection, if you want to access the features, just use:

```
states = data.features;
```

---

*Note*: This dataset came up in another [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49992075/7106086), the geojson isn't quite valid for use with d3 because there are points missing coordinates. You'll need to filter out those points missing coordinates prior to appending them, see this [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/49d0c7976d64d1df434b32c886ba7419) and/or the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `objects` member on the JSON returned by that API call (nor is there a `countries` member):

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    6.08333,
                    50.775
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "mass": "21",
                "name": "Aachen",
                "reclong": "6.083330",
                "geolocation_address": null,
                "geolocation_zip": null,
                "year": "1880-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                "geolocation_state": null,
                "fall": "Fell",
                "id": "1",
                "recclass": "L5",
                "reclat": "50.775000",
                "geolocation_city": null,
                "nametype": "Valid"
            }
        }
        /* ... */
    ],
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    }
}
```